# Why can't I convert this json to c#

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I trier to convert

> {["A","B"]}

With http://json2csharp.com/

But it says my expression is not valid.

Why This is not valid json expression ?

Comment: Its simply an array of strings. Json2Csharp is for entire objects. Are you expecting the tool to stub out an object with a single string array property?

Comment: Why the "javascript" tag?

Answer (score 8):

`{["A","B"]}` is **invalid** JSON. If you have this input then don't try to use a JSON serializer. JSON serializers work with JSON strings which is not what you have as input.

Your input should be: `{"array":["A","B"]}` or `["A","B"]`.

In the first case you could deserialize it to the following CLR class:

```
public class Model
{
    public string[] Array { get; set; }
}
```

and in the second directly to a `string[]`.

You could also use http://jsonlint.com/ to check whether your string is valid JSON or not.

Comment: the {} is an object and for that to be valid it has to be in the form of either empty object `{}` or `{"property1":"value1",...,"propertyN","valueN"}` on the other hand, arrays are ok with [{}] (array with one element: an empty object)